# jQuery.serialize returns nothing (The Input elements DO have a name...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

For some reason I can't get jQuery to serialize my form. performing a google search just pointed me to a bunch of similar questions where the O.P. forgot to give the inputs a "name". But that's not my issue, as my inputs DO have a name...

```
$('#time_clock_form').serialize();
```

returns nothing on this form

```
<form id="time_clock_form" method="POST">           
    <label for="id">Enter last four ligits of SSN</label>
    <input type="text" id="ssn" name="ssn" maxlength="4">
    <input name="submit" value="Punch Timeclock" type="submit">
</form>
```

I've been ripping my hair out all morning. I even went as far as giving the inputs closing tags. (Obviously, that didn't work)

Here is where i am serializing the data

```
    // When the user types in their ssn, punch the timeclock
    $('#ssn').on('input', function(){

        // When the user has input all 4 digits...
        if($(this).val().length === 4){
            // Disable the input (only until the AJAX request completes...)
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);

        console.log($('#time_clock_form').serialize());

            // Send the AJAX request to punch the time clock
            $.ajax({
                url     : 'AJAX_punchTimeClock.php',
                data    : $('#time_clock_form').serialize(),
                success : function(Result){

                    // We can't use $(this) here because it would refer to the AJAX request, and not the input. Don't you just LOVE context errors?
                    $('#ssn').prop('disabled', false);

                    console.log(Result);
                },
                error   : function(XHR, textError, error){

                }

            });
        }
    })
```

Comment: Typo, missing id selector: `$('time_clock_form')` -> `$('#time_clock_form')`

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. In my actual code I am using the ID selector. I was actually just trying to edit my original question

Comment: In that case what you have should (and does: https://jsfiddle.net/hzcuv42e/) work - assuming you `serialize()` the form at a point when all inputs have been given values

Comment: I updated the question with my serialize code. I've done this several times. I can't imaging why it's not working

Comment: Thanks for updating. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you disable the `input` before you serialize it. `serialize()` doesn't work on disabled form elements. Change the order of those statements:

```
$('#ssn').on('input', function() {
    if ($(this).val().length === 4) {
        // serialize the form and store the output here
        console.log($('#time_clock_form').serialize());

        // then disable the form...
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);

        // ajax...
    }
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/hzcuv42e/2/)